# How to change the width of b-table th

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to expand the rows of the table as in screenshot.How do I change the width of the th?
Is there any way how to add class to th

[I want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2pJs.png)

```
    logTableField: [
  { key: "LogDate", label: "Tarih",thClass: 'bg-white text-dark' },
  { key: "LogUser", label: "Analist" },
  { key: "Description", label: " İşlem Açıklaması" },
  { key: "LogText", label: "Kullanıcı Yorumu" },
],

           <b-tab title="Kayıt Logları" v-if="this.Logs != null">
          <b-table
            id="logTable"
            striped
            hover
            :items="Logs"
            :fields="logTableField"
            per-page="10"
            :current-page="currentPageLog"
          >
            <template slot="Description" slot-scope="row">
              <div v-html="row.item.Description"></div>
            </template>
          </b-table>
          <b-pagination
            v-model="currentPageLog"
            :total-rows="Logs.length"
            per-page="10"
            aria-controls="my-table"
          ></b-pagination>
        </b-tab>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) documentation for detailed styling on tables.

EDIT:

1. Please use lowercase variables.
2. Read the docs which are listed above
3. Why are your summed up widths not 100%?
4. If you in fact want to use classes, look up the answer from Stefanos_Apk which is perfect if there is more than one style attribute in my opinion

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-chandrasekhar-d5e2o?file=/src/components/Table.vue

```
logTableField: [
    {
      key: "logDate",
      label: "Tarih",
      thStyle: { width: "10%" },
    },
    { key: "logUser", label: "Analist", thStyle: { width: "20%" } },
    {
      key: "description",
      label: " İşlem Açıklaması",
      thStyle: { width: "20%" },
    },
    {
      key: "logText",
      label: "Kullanıcı Yorumu",
      thStyle: { width: "50%" },
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Code in your answer for how to solve this would be useful. If that URL you linked is down/unreachable this answer is of no use to anyone

Comment: i just wanted to encourage the author to read the docs first before posting. most of the time its faster to check the docs for yourself imho :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the thClass property inside of your field object. But tdClass just accepts a string or an array, not an object. So you can only reference to a css class.

```
logTableField: [
  { key: "LogDate", label: "Tarih", thClass: 'nameOfTheClass' },
  { key: "LogUser", label: "Analist", thClass: 'nameOfTheClas1' },
  { key: "Description", label: " İşlem Açıklaması", thClass: 'nameOfTheClass2' },
  { key: "LogText", label: "Kullanıcı Yorumu", thClass: 'nameOfTheClass3' },
]
```

and in your CSS:

```
 .nameOfTheClass {
      width: 10%
    },
.nameOfTheClass1 {
      width: 15%
    }
 .nameOfTheClass2 {
      width: 15%
    }
 .nameOfTheClass3 {
      width: 50%
    }
```